# Simple FFMpeg player for Android

Tags: android, c++, video, ffmpeg

I have a problem with the output of AVFrame (AVPicture) into the ANativeWindow. I wrote simpe test code:

```
void *Player::readThread(void * reserved) {
    ALOGD("Read thread started!");
    VideoState *state =  (VideoState *) reserved;

    int err = 0;
    int ret;
    int i;
    AVFormatContext *formatContext = NULL;
    AVCodecContext *codecContext = NULL;
    AVCodecParameters *codecParams = NULL;
    AVCodecID codecID = AV_CODEC_ID_NONE;
    AVCodec *decoder = NULL;
    AVFrame *frame = NULL;
    AVFrame *frameRGBA = NULL;
    AVPacket packet;
    struct SwsContext *img2RGBAContext;
    ANativeWindow_Buffer windowBuffer;
    uint8_t *RGBABuffer = NULL;
    int RGBABufferSize = 0;
    int got = 0;
    int windowWidth = 640;
    int windowHeight = 480;

    const char *url = state->url.c_str();
    if (url == NULL || strlen(url) <= 0) {
        err = ERROR_UNKNOWN_URI;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("URL to play: %s", url);

    state->isPlaying = true;

    formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (formatContext == NULL) {
        err = ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("formatContext allocated");

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (frame == NULL) {
        err = ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("frame allocated");

    frameRGBA = av_frame_alloc();
    if (frameRGBA == NULL) {
        err = ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("frameRGBA allocated");

    ret = avformat_open_input(&formatContext, url, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        err = ERROR_CAN_NOT_OPEN_URI;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("formatContext opened");

    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        err = ERROR_CAN_NOT_FIND_STREAM_INFO;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("file info found");

    for (i = 0; i < formatContext->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *stream = formatContext->streams[i];
        AVCodecParameters *codecParams = stream->codecpar;
        AVCodecID codecID = codecParams->codec_id;
        AVMediaType type = codecParams->codec_type;
        const char *codecName = avcodec_get_name(codecID);
        switch (type) {
            case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
                ALOGD("Stream [%d]: type=AUDIO codecName=%s",i,codecName);
                break;
            case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
                ALOGD("Stream [%d]: type=VIDEO codecName=%s",i,codecName);
                if (state->video_stream == -1) {
                    state->video_stream = i;
                }
                break;
            case AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE:
                ALOGD("Stream [%d]: type=SUBTITLE codecName=%s",i,codecName);
                break;
            default:
                ALOGD("Stream [%d]: type=UNKNOWN codecName=%s",i,codecName);
                break;
        }
    }

    if (state->video_stream == -1) {
        err = ERROR_CAN_NOT_FIND_ANY_STREAM;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("Video stream index: %d",state->video_stream);

    codecParams = formatContext->streams[state->video_stream]->codecpar;
    codecID = codecParams->codec_id;
    if (codecID == AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
        err = ERROR_UNKNOWN_CODEC;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("Codec found");

    decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(codecID);
    if (decoder == NULL) {
        err = ERROR_CAN_NOT_FIND_DECODER;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("Decoder found");

    codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder);
    if (codecContext == NULL) {
        err = ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("codecContext created");

    ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codecContext, codecParams);
    if (ret < 0) {
        err = ERROR_CAN_NOT_START_DECODER;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("codecContext params was set");

    ret = avcodec_open2(codecContext, decoder, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        err = ERROR_CAN_NOT_START_DECODER;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("Decoder opened");

    if (state->window != NULL) {
        ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(state->window, codecParams->width, codecParams->height, WINDOW_FORMAT_RGB_565);
        ALOGD("Window geometry changed");
    }

    if (codecParams->width>0 && codecParams->height>0) {
        ALOGD("Video width: %d\nVideo height: %d",codecParams->width, codecParams->height);
        img2RGBAContext = sws_getCachedContext(
            NULL,
            codecParams->width,
            codecParams->height,
            (AVPixelFormat)codecParams->format,
            codecParams->width,
            codecParams->height,
            AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565,
            SWS_BICUBIC,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);
        if (img2RGBAContext == NULL) {
            err = ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
            goto exit;
        }
    } else {
        err = ERROR_CAN_NOT_START_DECODER;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("img2RGBAContext created");

    RGBABufferSize = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565, codecParams->width, codecParams->height, 1);
    RGBABuffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(RGBABufferSize*sizeof(uint8_t));
    if (RGBABuffer == NULL) {
        err = ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        goto exit;
    }
    ALOGD("frameRGBABuffer size %d bytes",RGBABufferSize);

    ret = av_image_alloc(frameRGBA->data, frameRGBA->linesize, codecParams->width, codecParams->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565, 1);
    if (ret < 0) {
        err = ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        goto exit;
    }

    while (av_read_frame(formatContext, &packet) >= 0 && state->isPlaying) {
        if (packet.stream_index != state->video_stream) {
            ALOGD("Packet is not a video packet. Discard.");
            av_packet_unref(&packet);
            continue;
        }
        ret = avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, &packet);
        if (ret != 0) {
            ALOGE("Can not send packet to decode");
            av_packet_unref(&packet);
            continue;
        }
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(codecContext, frame);
        if (ret != 0) {
            ALOGE("Can not receive decoded frame yet");
            av_packet_unref(&packet);
            continue;
        }
        ALOGD("Converting image to RGB565...");
        sws_scale(img2RGBAContext, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, codecParams->height, frameRGBA->data, frameRGBA->linesize);
        ALOGD("Image converted to RGB565");
        av_image_copy_to_buffer(RGBABuffer,
            RGBABufferSize,
            frameRGBA->data,
            frameRGBA->linesize,
            AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565,
            codecParams->width,
            codecParams->height,
            1);
        ALOGD("Image wrote into frameRGBABuffer");
        if (ANativeWindow_lock(state->window, &windowBuffer, NULL) == 0) {
            ALOGD("Writing %d bytes to windowBuffer", RGBABufferSize);
            memcpy(windowBuffer.bits, RGBABuffer, RGBABufferSize);
            ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(state->window);
            ALOGD("Image displayed");
        } else {
            ALOGE("Can not display frame");
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }

    exit:
    ALOGD("Releasing resources...");
    if (err!=0) {
        state->isPlaying = false;
        #if !LOG_NDEBUG
            switch (err) {
                case  ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                    ALOGE("Out of memory!");
                    break;
                case  ERROR_CAN_NOT_OPEN_URI:
                    ALOGE("Can not open URI: %s", url);
                    break;
                case  ERROR_UNKNOWN_URI:
                    ALOGE("Unknown URI to open!");
                    break;
                default:
                    ALOGE("Unknown error");
                    break;
            }
        #endif
        // TODO: send error to listener
    }
    sws_freeContext(img2RGBAContext);
    free(RGBABuffer);
    av_free(frame);
    av_freep(&frameRGBA->data[0]);
    av_packet_unref(&packet);
    avcodec_close(codecContext);
    avformat_close_input(&formatContext);
    avformat_free_context(formatContext);
    ALOGD("Read thread closed!");
}
```

I faced with the next problem in some videos:
[image]
For example, this video gives me next logs:

```
10-23 14:53:42.212 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Read thread started!
10-23 14:53:42.212 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: URL to play: http://www.ex.ua/load/280797285
10-23 14:53:42.212 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: formatContext allocated
10-23 14:53:42.212 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: frame allocated
10-23 14:53:42.212 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: frameRGBA allocated
10-23 14:53:42.846 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: formatContext opened
10-23 14:53:42.879 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: file info found
10-23 14:53:42.879 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Stream [0]: type=VIDEO codecName=h264
10-23 14:53:42.879 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Stream [1]: type=AUDIO codecName=ac3
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Stream [2]: type=AUDIO codecName=ac3
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Stream [3]: type=AUDIO codecName=ac3
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Stream [4]: type=SUBTITLE codecName=subrip
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Video stream index: 0
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Codec found
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Decoder found
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: codecContext created
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: codecContext params was set
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Decoder opened
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Window geometry changed
10-23 14:53:42.880 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Video width: 1024
                                                             Video height: 424
10-23 14:53:42.882 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: img2RGBAContext created
10-23 14:53:42.882 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: frameRGBABuffer size 868352 bytes
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer E/Player: Can not receive decoded frame yet
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.889 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.890 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Packet is not a video packet. Discard.
10-23 14:53:42.899 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer E/Player: Can not receive decoded frame yet
10-23 14:53:42.905 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Converting image to RGB565...
10-23 14:53:42.918 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Image converted to RGB565
10-23 14:53:42.919 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Image wrote into frameRGBABuffer
10-23 14:53:42.920 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Writing 868352 bytes to windowBuffer
10-23 14:53:42.921 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Image displayed
10-23 14:53:42.926 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Converting image to RGB565...
10-23 14:53:42.934 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Image converted to RGB565
10-23 14:53:42.935 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Image wrote into frameRGBABuffer
10-23 14:53:42.936 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Writing 868352 bytes to windowBuffer
10-23 14:53:42.937 26970-4527/com.don.ffmpegplayer D/Player: Image displayed
```

What am I doing wrong? If I understood correctly, I need to follow next steps:

1. Get decoded AVFrame from decoder
2. Convert AVFrame data to RGB565 or RGB8888
3. Get pixel data from converted frame
4. Write it to native window

But in this code two points confuse me: is `ANative_setBuffersGeometry` called correctly and why `frameRGBABuffer` size is 868352 bytes? If video size is 1024*424 `frameRGBABuffer` size must be `width*height*4`, isn't it? If I change `frameRGBABuffer` size to `width*height*4` program carashes after first image diplayed. I pass video dimmensions to `ANative_setBuffersGeometry`.

For any help thanks in anvance.

Comment: Ok, about frameRGBABuffer size - it is correct, because RGB565 is 2 bytes long, that's why frameRGBABuffer size twice smaller than RGBA8888, but question about NativeWindow is still actual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in width of video and value that I pass into `ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry`. I do not know why, but `ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry` can correct handle only `640, 1280, 1920` as a width parameter, height - any wanted. If I set any other width - problem apperars as on screenshot.